# c++ design (multiple inheritance vs. listing relevant data)

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have

```
class Skill
{
public :
  virtual void printSkill();
//....
}

class Person : public Skill
{


//...
}
```

In previous design Person could have one skill per person and I could print it

```
Person p;
p.printSkill();
```

Now we want to add multiple skill and display them.
I changed:

```
class Person
{
private:
vector<Skill*> m_skills;
pubcic:
void addSkill(Skill *s) { m_skills.push_back(s);}
void printSkills() const { 
  for auto it = m_skills.begin(); it != m_skills.end(); ++it)
  {
      it->printSkill();
  }
}
}
class Skill1 : public Skill
{
   void printSkill() ;
}

class Skill2 : public Skill
{
   void printSkill() ;
}

Person p;
Skill1 s1;
Skill2 s2;
p.addSkill(&s1);
p.addSkill(&s2);
```

This should work
But I dont like this. may be I can solve this without `addSkill` method? Using MultipleInheitance?

Answer (score 1):

What's best depends on a large number of factors.

With your `vector<Skill*>` version:

- The same `Skill`-derived object may be added to multiple `Person` objects, which might be memory efficient and desirable, or inappropriate (e.g. if the Skills objects had to have `Person`-specific data members, such as the extent of skill, e.g. a bench-press skill might want a number of kgs specific to the `Person`)
- There's no inherent management of the lifetime of the `Skills`-derived objects, which must never-the-less outlive any use of them via the pointers to them you're storing in `Person` objects, or you'll get *undefined behaviour*.  This may be fine: perhaps you can create some set number of skills once in the program lifetime, and not need to destruct them until after all the `Person` objects' lifetimes.  At other times, the calling code will have take extra responsibility and care.

Other possible approaches include:

Having `Person` store a `vector<unique_ptr<Skill>>`, and have client code hand over ownership to the skills objects it adds: `addSkill(std::make_unique<SomeSkill>(constructor, args, la, de, da);`

You could also have a `using SomeSkill = std::variant<Skill1, Skill2, Skill3>;` and have `Person` store a `std::vector<SomeSkill>`.  This achieves something similar to the last, but using a buffer inside the variant big enough to store the largest `Skill`-derived object, instead of storing pointers off to dynamically allocated `Skill` objects.

You could use multiple inheritance, but then you'd have multiple base classes providing a same-named function, and to call a specific one you have to disambiguate that at the time.  If you want to be able to easily declare `Person`s with different skills, and still have a `printSkills` function that automatically discovers and prints the individual skills from the multiple bases, that's possible using variadic templates and parameter packs, but judging from the question - respectfully - you're not ready to go down that route.